# Error al compilar: ([Warning]unknown scape sentence "\040 [enabled by default])"

Tags: c++, dev-c++, printf

Estoy intentado resolver unos ejercicios de c++ en devc++ y al imprimir en pantalla con `prinft` me aparece un error que dice:

> ```
> ([Warning]unknown scape sentence "\040 [enabled by default])".
> ```

Me aparece en el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int dos,cuatro;
    float uno,f_cuatro;

    // ...

    printf("\n1/3 %2f\valor maximo %d\tres numeros %d\%d\%d\entero y flotante %d\ %f,"uno, dos, 20, 30, 40, 50, 54.005);    

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Según tú, ¿ que es `2 ^ 32` ?

Comment: Es el valor maximo que puede almacenar un int, osea 2147483647.

Comment: Pues va a ser que no. `^` es XOR binario (a nivel de bits). C++ **no tiene** operador de elevar a potencia.

Comment: Mmmmm ya entonces, no estoy potenciando 2 a la 32, seria con la libreria math.h y pow??

Comment: Para `double` si. Para enteros, no hay. **Pero** para saber el valor máximo de un `int`, se usa la `template std::numeric_limits`. En concreto, `std::numeric_limits< int >::max( )`. Del *header* `#include <limits>`.

Comment: Estuve mirando lo que me dijiste se usa asi como ya tengo el std. numeric_limits< int >:: max(30)?

Comment: No hombre xD. `numeric_limits< int >::max( );` a secas. El resultado es un `int`, **no** un float, así que tendrás que cambiar lo necesario.

Comment: XD, lo sospeche desde un principio, discúlpame es que estoy muy nuevo en este tema. Ojala se pudiera abrir el chat la verdad tengo otras preguntas si no es mucha molestia.

Comment: Te faltan puntos aún para poder usar el chat. Aunque yo no es que sea tampoco muy experto que digamos ... Tendrás que escribir alguna pregunta mas, hasta que llegues a los 20 puntos (creo) para el chat.

Comment: Igualmente gracias Dolmenes por su colaboracion, me sirvio de mucha ayuda.